# Where should CakePHP webroot be from apache configuration?

Tags: php, apache, cakephp

I've noticed that there is an `index.php` file on the root of the cakePHP folder, under`app/`, and under `app/webroot`.

My understanding is that the apache configuration should point to `app/webroot` as the site root, because otherwise I may be exposing my code and other sensitive data (database connection credentials etc). In my testing environment, I used to point it to the root folder of my cakePHP folder and **it worked as expected**(!) and I successfully completed the `Blog` tutorial.

Then I realized that I may be doing a mistake and I pointed apache to `app/webroot` and it still works as intended.

If this is the case, why doesn't cakePHP make it more clear by not having multiple `index.php` files and clearly stating that the site's root location should be pointed to `app/webroot` ?

Comment: It makes it quite clear: http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/installation.html#production

Answer (score 0):

> If this is the case, what doesn't cakePHP make it more clear by not
>   having multiple index.php files and clearly stating that the site's
>   root location should be pointed to app/webroot ?

Guess  because it was thought to be newbie friendly but this makes it easy to configure it wrong and expose the whole app to the public which is not a good idea.

See http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/installation.html#production

But yes, I agree to some extend, this could be a little more clear about the reason. 
You should always use the webroot folder and nothing except your tmp folder of the app should be writeable by the webserver user of your system.

Answer (score 0):

With some hosting providers it is not possible to put anything "below" public_html. In these cases CakePHP provides both an index.php and .htaccess in both root, app and webroot dir. This is there to have it working in several different hosting environments without the user having to change anything.

If at all possible you should only expose the webroot dir